# Python errors when printing PHP variable - using sys

Tags: php, python, variables, sys

I have been trying to solve this for hours but have been unsuccessful. I have searched similar questions but they haven't helped!

PHP file - written in Notepad++:

```
<?php
$item='example';
$tmp = shell_exec("C:\Python34\python.exe TestingStuff.py .$item");
echo $tmp;
?>
```

When running this file in a browser (using Apache), I the following outputs:

```
['TestingStuff.py', '.example'] .example
```

Python file - written in IDLE:

```
#!c:\python34\python.exe

import sys 
print(sys.argv[1])
```

I receive the following error when running this:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When running `print(sys.argv)` the output is `['C:/xampp/htdocs/TestingStuff.py']`

Comment: How are you running the script? How are you passing an argument to it?

Comment: It's not clear when it's not working. When are you receiving the error? 'Cause when running from Apache you say you get an output, so the python script is working.

Comment: just use `print(sys.argv[0])` the first arg is argv[0] arrays starts with zero index